# doxygen comment in fortran codeblock in doxygen markdown file not printed

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm writing a markdown file with some code examples. In one example I want to show how to comment the code using doxygen comments:

```
Here is normal text.

~~~.f90
!> Here is a doxygen comment in a fortran code example
!! that should be visible in the doxygen output
Here comes some more code
~~~
```

The code is printed nicely, but the comment is not shown in the output. Instead there is just a blank line. When I change the example to use the code block markup indicated by four leading spaces, the code highlight get's lost. I guess that is because the code isn't marked as fortran.

So the questions are:

- How to get the comment visible when using the fenced code region.

or

- How to get the code formatted as fortran code when using the leading space code region indication.

Comment: The !> and !! are seen as normal comment signs (no special processing. By means of setting STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS to NO you can get this information.

Comment: @albert Would this be an answer, I could promote it and mark it as the solution. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert) does not want to answer my question, I'll do on his behalf:

The !> and !! are seen as normal comment signs (no special processing). By means of setting STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS to NO you can get this information.